# A function $f:A\to B$ is injective iff $(f^{-1} \circ f)(V)=V$ for every set $V$ that's a subset of $A$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove this property for injective functions, but I'm not sure I'm getting anywhere. I tried by assuming that $f$ is not injective, and then concluding that there must exist an $x$ that is different from $y$, such that the value of $f$ of those is equal to some $z$. But then, when we look at the set $\{x,y\}$, it is a subset of $f^{-1} (f({x}))$, but this is different from $\{x\}$, and that leads us into a contradiction. I'd like to assume this part is ok so far, but I would still like some assurance.

I get stuck when I assume now that $f$ is an injective function. I now have an arbitrary $x$ that is from the set $V$, and then I know there is a $y$ that's an element of $f^{-1}(f(V))$, but I cannot get to the end of the proof.

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Hint: If $f:A\to B$ is injective, then $f:A\to f(A)$ is bijective.

Comment: Hint: if $f(x) = f(y)$, consider $f^{-1}(f(\{z\}))$ for $z = x, y$ and use this to prove $x = y$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:A\to B$ is injective.

Let $x\in V$. Then $f(x)\in f(V)$. Therefore, $x\in f^{-1}(f(V))$. Hence, $V\subseteq f^{-1}(f(V))$.

Let $x\in f^{-1}(f(V))$. Then $f(x)\in f(V)$. So, there exists $v\in V$ such that $f(x)=f(v)$. Since $f$ in injective, $x=v$. Therefore, $x\in V$. Hence, $f^{-1}(f(V))\subseteq V$.

Thus, $V= f^{-1}(f(V))$.

---

Suppose $V= f^{-1}(f(V))$ for all $V\subseteq A$.

Let $x,y\in A$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$, which means that $f(\{x\})=f(\{y\})$. Then $f^{-1}(f(\{x\}))=f^{-1}(f(\{y\}))$. Since $\{x\},\{y\}\subseteq A$, we have $\{x\}=\{y\}$, by our assumption. Hence, $x=y$.

Thus, $f:A\to B$ is injective.